# How to copy data over into my custom database table

Tags: wordpress, wpallimport

I have the following function which inserts data from the postmeta table into a custom database table wp_fixtures_results.

I am using WPAll Import Plugin action `pmxi_saved_post`. So the code runs during an import process.

The purpose of the code is to migrate data from wp_postmeta into `wp_fixtures_results` which is the custom table.

When running the code for a fresh import, the data is stored which is ordinarily stored in wp_postmeta is the moved into the custom table. This works perfectly.

However, the data only runs for the INSERT query as shown in the code. Using the same plugin action I need to update the data from postmeta into the custom table. The issue is the code is only working for the INSERT query. How do I check if the data has changed in the postmeta and during the import process which updates the data, update the custom table too?

```
if ($post_type === 'fixture-result') {
    function save_fr_data_to_custom_database_table($post_id)
    {
        // Make wpdb object available.
        global $wpdb;

        // Retrieve value to save.
        $value = get_post_meta($post_id, 'fixtures_results', true);

        // Define target database table.
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "fixtures_results";

        // Insert value into database table.
        $wpdb->insert($table_name, array('ID' => $post_id, 'fixtures_results' => $value), array('%d', '%s'));

        // Update query not working - doesn't change data.
        $wpdb->update($table_name, array('ID' => $post_id, 'fixtures_results' => $value), array('%d', '%s'));

        // Delete temporary custom field.
        delete_post_meta($post_id, 'fixtures_results');
        
    }

    add_action('pmxi_saved_post', 'save_fr_data_to_custom_database_table', 10, 1);
    
}
```

**The wp_postmeta table**
[image]

**The wp_fixtures_results (custom table)**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question by now, but I'd say that the $wpdb->update is redundant. The insert is going to create the row and store the fields. The $wpdb->insert should return "1" - check that value to verify that the insert succeeded before deleting the postmeta entry. The call to update is not necessary.